# How to delete a local notification in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am making an application that sets a local notification.

Thankfully I was able to set the local notification but I don't know how to delete the notification which is set by my application.

The XCode does provide functionality of delete with `removeAllNotifications` but you cannot remove specific notifications set by the application.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340664/delete-a-particular-local-notification

Answer (score 71):

You asked this question twice, so I'm answering on both questions in the hopes of it reaching you:

Cancel all local notifications with this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

---

Cancel one local notification with this line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:theNotification];
```

where `theNotification` is a `UILocalNotification` object, so in order to cancel a specific notification you need to hold on to it's `UILocalNotification`.

---

You can find more stuff in [apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html).

Comment: Hi Thomas, where would you save or get that notification object?

Comment: If you don't want to cancel all notifications, you'll have to hold the NSNotification you might want to cancel in memory somewhere. Maybe a property of an appropriate class that holds an array of NSNotifications.

Comment: thomas, I have found the answer by serializing the UILocalNotification object

Answer (score 12):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification]
```

Answer (score 2):

helloou, look, in swift you can create a local notification :

```
var notif = UILocalNotification()
        notif.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

        let morningOfChristmasComponents = NSDateComponents()
        morningOfChristmasComponents.year = 2016
        morningOfChristmasComponents.month = 03
        morningOfChristmasComponents.day = 30
        morningOfChristmasComponents.hour = 15
        morningOfChristmasComponents.minute = 59
        morningOfChristmasComponents.second = 0

        let morningOfChristmas = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(morningOfChristmasComponents)!

        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
        formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle

        let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(morningOfChristmas)

        notif.fireDate = morningOfChristmas
        notif.alertBody = "alarma wolf"
        notif.userInfo = ["identificador": "wolf"]
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notif)
        print("alarma fijada para \(dateString)")
```

loo the userInfo is a indeitifer to you local notification, now, if you want delete a specific local notificaction please try:

```
var uidtodelete = "wolf"
        var app:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        for oneEvent in app.scheduledLocalNotifications! {
            var notification = oneEvent as UILocalNotification
            let userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo! as! [String:AnyObject]
            let uid = userInfoCurrent["identificador"]! as! String
            if uid == uidtodelete {
                //Cancelling local notification
                app.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
                break;
            }
        }
```

look the method, above, userInfoCurrent is the identificator of your's local notification, and uitodelete is a string that contain the specific key of the locla notification that you want delete...

aaaa... if you want to delete all local notification you can use

UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()

oki

I hope you serve yourself or someone else this information..

good bye, andforgive my bad English

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel notification by following function:`[[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelNotification:object Of your UILocalNotification]`

Comment: This doesn't take out the 1 with the circle around it on the app icon though. Is there a way to take this out?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [User Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) framework, available since iOS 10.0, given the identifier you provided is `foo`:

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: "foo")
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: "foo")
```

Or in Objective-C :

```objectivec
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] removePendingNotificationRequestsWithIdentifiers:@[@"foo"]];
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] removeDeliveredNotificationsWithIdentifiers:@[@"foo"]];
```