# Clearing the badge when received Push Notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, push-notification

How can I clear the badge which appears on application icon when I receive Push Notification? I want to clear it once user has either tapped on "View" of Push notification alert or has tapped on the app icon.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I suspect you are talking about the SpringBoard's badge:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Badge count set Zero

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0]
```

Cancel all local notifications with this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Cancel one local notification with this line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:theNotification];
```

here theNotification is a UILocalNotification object, so in order to cancel a specific notification, you need to hold on to it's UILocalNotification.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372387/how-to-delete-a-local-notification-in-iphone).

Answer (score 2):

For Mac OS X Lion, it's:

```
    [NSApp dockTile].badgeLabel = @"";
```

(Lion supports badge-type push notifications.)

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's documentation, set the `application.applicationIconBadgeNumber` to the number you want displayed on the badge. If you set it to 0, it will be cleared.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (localNotif) {
        NSString *itemName = [localNotif.userInfo objectForKey:ToDoItemKey];
        [viewController displayItem:itemName];  // custom method
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber-1;
    }

    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

[Reference - Scroll down to the **Handling Local and Remote Notifications** section just above listing 2.4](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)