# iOS application: how to clear notifications?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

I've an iOS application where some Push Notification are sent to. My problem is, that the messages/notifications stays in the Notification Center in iOS after then are tapped. How can I remove a notification for my application in the Notification Center next time the application opens?

I came across posts where people are calling `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber` to a zero-value to clear the notifications. That's seems very weird to me, so I believe that maybe another solution exists?

**EDIT1:**

I'm having some problems clearing the notifications. Please see my code here:

```
- (void) clearNotifications {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (dictionary != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);

            [self clearNotifications];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{    
    NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
    [self clearNotifications];
}
```

I'm running the App through Xcode. When the App is minimized and I start the App using the notification in the Notification Center, I can see in the log, that the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called and using breakpoints I can see, that the `clearNotifications` has ran. But still the notification hangs in the Notification Center. Why?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Most likely because Notification Center is a relatively new feature, Apple didn't necessarily want to push a whole new paradigm for clearing notifications. So instead, they multi-purposed `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];` to clear said notifications. It might seem a bit weird, and Apple might provide a more intuitive way to do this in the future, but for the time being it's the official way.

Myself, I use this snippet:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

which never fails to clear all of the app's notifications from Notification Center.

Comment: cancelAllLocalNotifications is Deprecated - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622990-cancelalllocalnotifications?language=objc

You need to use 
`let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications() // To remove all delivered notifications`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40397907/1155650

Answer (score 120):

Just to expand on pcperini's answer. As he mentions you will need to add the following code to your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method;

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

You **Also** need to increment then decrement the badge in your `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method if you are trying to clear the message from the message centre so that when a user enters you app from pressing a notification the message centre will also clear, ie;

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Comment: I think cancelAllLocalNotifications is not required.Worked for me without that line

Comment: @Murali would that depend on you using **local** notifications or not...?

Comment: UPDATE::
“cancelAllLocalNotifications' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0”
So if your app version is higher than iOS10.0 then you should use this

UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center removeAllDeliveredNotifications];
[center removeAllPendingNotificationRequests];

Answer (score 21):

It might also make sense to add a call to clearNotifications in applicationDidBecomeActive so that in case the application is in the background and comes back it will also clear the notifications.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self clearNotifications];
}
```

Answer (score 18):

## **Update for iOS 10 (Swift 3)**

**In order to clear all local notifications in iOS 10 apps, you should use the following code:**

```swift
import UserNotifications

...

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() // To remove all pending notifications which are not delivered yet but scheduled.
    center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications() // To remove all delivered notifications
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
}
```

This code handles the clearing of local notifications for iOS 10.x and all preceding versions of iOS. You will need to `import UserNotifications` for the iOS 10.x code.

Answer (score 9):

If you have pending scheduled local notifications and don't want to use `cancelAllLocalNotifications` to clear old ones in Notification Center, you can also do the following:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications = [UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications;
```

It appears that if you set the `scheduledLocalNotifications` it clears the old ones in Notification Center, and by setting it to itself, you retain the pending local notifications.

Comment: This works like a charm for me on iOS 9. I didn't want to cancel all my notifications because they repeat in time (daily or weekly). And this way I clear all the stuff without deleting them.

Comment: Best solution I have seen so far. Anyone know if it works on iOS 8?

Comment: @duncanc4 last time I tested it on iOS 8 it was working.

Comment: Where within the app would you call this?

Comment: Alex, you should call it whenever you need to clear out the notifications in the Notification Center. I call it in both my AppDelegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` methods.

Comment: You cannot call this method immediately after receiving local notification because you will receive tens of hundreds notification. Maybe the same notification apply again, and now is the time to fire, so you keep fire, apply again, fire, apply....

Comment: @zgjie I've been using this without any issues for a while now and just tried your use case and was unable to reproduce. I'd be very interested if you have a sample project that can reproduce this.

Comment: Very nice! But is this documented functionality or 'just' a side effect of the current implementation which may change in any minor/major iOS update?

Comment: @meaning-matters As far as I know this is not documented and it could change in an iOS update. However, also as far as I know there is no official way of doing this. If you look at the other answers they are all just "hacks" to clear out stale notifications from the notification center. For example the top answers have you clear out the badge and end all pending local notifications. Neither have anything to do with clearing out old/stale notifications from notification center. This particular answer solved the problem and allowed me to keep pending/scheduled notifications.

Answer (score 4):

If you're coming here wondering the opposite (as I was), [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7598) post may be for you.

I couldn't figure out why my notifications were clearing when I cleared the badge...I manually increment the badge and then want to clear it when the user enters the app. That's no reason to clear out the notification center, though; they may still want to see or act on those notifications.

Negative 1 does the trick, luckily:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
```

Comment: Does it work for you in iOS9? I didn't noticed any difference with setting a badge to 0 or to -1. It still clears all remote notifications in my case.

Comment: Ya, I actually started noticing that with my app again; I have no idea what changed.

Comment: I'm giving up since Apple somehow decided that app with no badge number should have no any notifications

Answer (score 3):

In Swift I'm using the following code inside my AppDelegate:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    application.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in case there are scheduled alarms and uncleared app icon badges.

```
NSArray *scheduledLocalNotifications = [application scheduledLocalNotifications];
NSInteger applicationIconBadgeNumber = [application applicationIconBadgeNumber];

[application cancelAllLocalNotifications];
[application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

for (UILocalNotification* scheduledLocalNotification in scheduledLocalNotifications) {
    [application scheduleLocalNotification:scheduledLocalNotification];
}
[application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:applicationIconBadgeNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have repeated notifications at future, you do not want to cancel those notifications, you can clear the item in notification center by:

```
func clearNotificationCenter() {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

You cannot clear notification when your app is open in the foreground by calling the method below immediately after receiving local notification, otherwise you will receive tens of hundreds of notifications. Maybe because the same notification apply again, and now is the time to fire, so you keep fire, apply again, fire, apply....:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications = [UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you logout from your app, at that time you have to use a below line of code on your logout button click method.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

and this works perfectly in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code in your AppDelegate `applicationDidBecomeActive` method.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341476/5750651). It works for iOS 9

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
{
    UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
    //Cancelling local notification
    [app cancelLocalNotification:oneEvent];
}
```