# iOS remove notification from notification center

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS application: how to clear notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682051/ios-application-how-to-clear-notifications)

is there a way how to remove notification from notification center(iOS 5) when I click it and start my application ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property of your `UIApplication` instance to 0. That is,

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Edit: In the current iOS SDK, you can't remove just a single notification from the Notification Center programatically.

Comment: This only remove number from app icon for me, but not clear notification center ... what is wrong ?

Comment: Its a local notification or remote notification?

Comment: After a bit of searching, I've found a dupe which is a much better answer than this. Have a look at my comment on your answer.

Comment: Yes this is great, thanks a lot, but this solution clear all notifications from notification center and I want clear only notification which I click ...

Comment: How come this is marked as the correct answer when you wanted to delete one notification and the answer deletes all of them? Did you find a way to delete only one notification?

Comment: Hi, Am also having same problem. Is there any way to delete selected notification from the notification center?

Comment: There's no supported way to remove exactly one notification. Stupid limit, but there we go.

Comment: I had to add [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]; to get it to work.

Comment: How do applications like Skype, Yo solve this problem?