# iOS Sample Code to clear my application notification from Notification Center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I have been looking for a way to write a method that I can call on a button inside my application to remove all notifications that was received from server side , and delete all notifications from the notification center iOS , I have tried all the suggested solutions , :

[iOS remove notification from notification center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978538/ios-remove-notification-from-notification-center)

[iOS application: how to clear notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682051/ios-application-how-to-clear-notifications)

[iOS application: how to clear notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682051/ios-application-how-to-clear-notifications)

is there any way that I could get handle for the notification inside the notification center and do clear or delete

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all ,

I have solved my problem after trying so many codes , I called a method on a button and it worked with this snippet:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
```

Regards,