# iPhone: how to remove notification from notification center

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a provider which sends Push notifications to my iPhone. If I'm on home screen, I click on push notification in notification center and my app become open. Then I close my app, but notification is still in notification center...Why ? I already read that, why its not disappear ? How to remove this notification after I close my app ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS application: how to clear notifications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682051/ios-application-how-to-clear-notifications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the notifications using the below code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

This will remove all the app's notification from Notification Center.

Comment: But I dont want to set my badge to 0. What if I have badge with 43 unread messages in app, and then I have one new push notification, i should set badge 0 instead of 44 ?

Answer (score 1):

WHen are you want to remove the badge from the application just value of the badge number assign to 0 is means automatically remove the badges.

```
   - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
             [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    }
```

Comment: But I dont want to set my badge to 0. What if I have badge with 43 unread messages in app, and then I have one new push notification, i should set badge 0 instead of 44 ?

Comment: Hello Jim, In means when the application come form background then it's badge value being 0;

Comment: For that we put this code into appdelegate inside applicationWillEnterForeground method.