# iOS didReceiveRemoteNotification called, but Notification pulldown not cleared

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

simple code:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
  return YES; 
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
  NSLog(@"%@", deviceToken);
  // code that sends token to server
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
  NSLog(@"%@", deviceToken);
  // code that sends token to server
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
 // put up an alert with notification text
}
```

But the dropdown still contains the test from the alert.  I see other programs clearing their notifications.  Is it automatic, or programming required?  I could find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Can you be more precise?

Comment: @MiguelC. it was a duplicate, see accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear your apps's notifications in notification center by setting the badge number to 0 like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

More info here: [iOS application: how to clear notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682051/ios-application-how-to-clear-notifications)

Comment: I had to do setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1, setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0 to get it to work...  Clear the local notifications wasn't needed.