# Hide, do not display remote notification from code (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

is it possible to do not display or even cancel remote notification after receive it on device from code?

Regards,
Radek

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS application: how to clear notifications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682051/ios-application-how-to-clear-notifications)

Comment: I don't mean all notification, I mean particle - depending on notification content.

Comment: then check your payload contains values are same remove the particular else do nothing

Comment: Be specific - Why would you send notifications if you want to cancel it?

Comment: Some notification can be marked by user as a SPAM but not all - user decides. Yes there exists some workarounds but my question is simple - is it possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will send silent push notification from my server and then based on payload I will show or not local notification alert with sound.
What do you think?

I know how to clear existing notifications but I mean cancel before this notification appears in UI. Maybe I was not so precise in my question.

Tx for help.

Comment: did u ever figure out how to do this?