# Clear received LocalNotification notifications

Tags: swift

I have created notifications with `UILocalNotification()` and I'm trying to clear the received notifications, without removing the rest that are scheduled.

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

However this seems to delete all scheduled, is there not a `clearRescivedNotifcations()` ?

Comment: why not just `UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0`

Comment: Are you trying to clear the notifications that have already been delivered to the user? I think you can't do that.

Comment: @LeoDabus yeh I want to clear the notifications that have been delivered if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31039760/2303865

Comment: You need to clear all and  reschedule them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @LeoDabus I found the answer on [iOS application: how to clear notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682051/ios-application-how-to-clear-notifications/31039760#31039760)

Converted an answer from objective-c to swift

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications = UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications
```

This removes all notifications from the notification centre & keeps anything scheduled.