# Managing Push notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, ios10

I am using Urban Airship to receive push notification in my iOS 10 (Swift) app. I am running with following problems, requesting your help to resolve.

**Unable to hide notification when app is running foreground**

To hide notification, I have tried following tasks..

1. Remove implementation of delegate method func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                               willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                               withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
2. I tried to pass completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone)
   to escape / hide notification toast, but "UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone" is no more available.
3. completionHandler([]) -- This does not work.
   I have tried to pass "UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone" in

**Clear Notification**

How to clear/remove delivered(Once user read or cancel) notification from list and update the badge icon accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: @rmaddy could you please tell me , which method gets executed when the app is in background and receive notification?

Answer (score 0):

**Foreground Presentation Handling**

There are two ways to handle foreground presentation options on iOS10+ with the Urban Airship SDK. If you have an instance of [`UAPushNotificationDelegate`](https://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ios/latest/Protocols/UAPushNotificationDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)UAPushNotificationDelegate(im)presentationOptionsForNotification:) configured on the Urban Airship SDK then presentation options will be delegated to [`presentationOptions`](https://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ios/latest/Protocols/UAPushNotificationDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)UAPushNotificationDelegate(im)presentationOptionsForNotification:) and handled per push. For example:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func presentationOptions(for notification: UNNotification) -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions {
    return [.alert]
}
```

You can return `[]` to not present anything.

Otherwise, if you do not have the aforementioned delegate configured you can disable all foreground presentation options by setting the `defaultPresentationOptions`.

```
UAirship.push().defaultPresentationOptions = []
```

**Clearing Notifications**

On iOS10+ you can clear your app's notifications via the shared instance of [`UNUserNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter) which provides a [`removeAllDeliveredNotifications()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649502-removealldeliverednotifications)method. To maintain compatibility on older versions of iOS you can fall back to setting the badge to zero-- more information about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8682811/3100945).

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
};
```

Comment: Could you please tell me which method gets executed when the app is in background and receive notifivation?