# removing Notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I made an app that has custom notifications, but I cant remove them no matter what I do.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:[idkey objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

That is the code I use for removal; If I use all it works. The `idkey` is the correct
value, and its a number in a string, `@"3"` in this case.

This is a part of the saving function:

```
-(void) addNewNotificationWithKey:(NSString*)key {

    NSLog(@"%@",key);

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate = [tempFormatter dateFromString:datuminura];
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        notif.alertBody = description1;
        notif.alertAction = @"Open";
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which notification you want to remove and use following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340664/delete-a-particular-local-notification) to cancel it.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
{
    UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = oneEvent.userInfo;
    NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"uid"]];
    if ([uid isEqualToString:uidtodelete])
    {
        //Cancelling local notification
        [app cancelLocalNotification:oneEvent];
        break;
    }
}
```

[EDIT]

Add following line into your local notification to make [uid isEqualToString:uidtodelete] condition work.

```
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[idkey objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] forKey:@"uid"]; 
notif.userInfo = infoDict;
```

Comment: the sice of the array is always 4

Comment: all works fine just   if ([uid isEqualToString:[idkey objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) wont quiet work and i dont know wy

Comment: You need to set that id in the user info of your local notification. See edited code.