# UILocalNotification is fired even when the event to be fired is deleted from DB(Core Data)

Tags: ios

This might not be a difficult question to answer for many of you,but would you let me know why the **notification** is fired, even though i **delete the event** for it from **DataBase(Core-Data)**.

Thank You,

Best Regards.

Comment: Do you call cancelLocalNotification when you delete your event? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340664/delete-a-particular-local-notification

Comment: Nope i did not use it.I believe it is helpful in the case where you want to remove the UILocalNotification when the event is fired.Probably IM not too sure. @verbumdei

Comment: When i click a button that Clears the DB, Notifications still tend to pop even the event is no longer available in DB. @verbumdei

Comment: It is because core data records are not in any way linked to the local notification unless you link them together. When you schedule a local notification, you can assign an identifier in the user info. When you remove an event, you need to cancel the local notification with the same identifier.

Comment: That sounds pretty useful @verbumdei , but it would be great help if you give me a sample for doing so.                                          I have written this on click of SAVE button that saves data to DB

Comment: `UILocalNotification *lc=[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            lc.fireDate= objDate;
            lc.alertBody=@"Hey Sam it's time for some work";
            lc.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            lc.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            lc.alertAction=@"OK";
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:lc]; 
    
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove notification with the help of notification ID.

Comment: Please give an example or sample todo so @user2339310.

Comment: NSString *myIDToCancel = @"some_id_to_cancel";
UILocalNotification *notificationToCancel=nil;
for(UILocalNotification *aNotif in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) {
  if([[aNotif.userInfo objectForKey:@"ID"] isEqualToString:myIDToCancel]) {
     notificationToCancel=aNotif;
     break;
  }
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notificationToCancel];

Comment: :Buddy where MI suppose to write this on the click of save button that saves the data or in some delegate method.             `UILocalNotification *lc=[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            lc.fireDate= objDate;
            lc.alertBody=@"Hey Sam it's time for some work";
            lc.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            lc.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            lc.alertAction=@"OK";
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:lc]; 
    
`

Comment: From where you want to remove notification.

Comment: I dont want the notification to fire when the event is deleted from DB.hierarchy is : i have 3fields and i have a save button that triggers notification to fire based on the time set.But when i clear the DB the notification still fires even thou there is nothing in the DB.I Hope you get it.If not share your e-mail add i will mail you the code.

Comment: So, when you add event to database add notification with ID. When you delete event from database, in same function you can delete that notification with the help of Id which you get from database.

Comment: KKK i'l try doing that.Will get to you once its done.ThanK you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **cancelLocalNotification** to stop firing the **UILocalNotification**

**EDIT**

I added here a method to cancel local notification. You need to maintain an id in the 
notification.userInfo(dictionary) for every notifications. if you want to cancel notification pass the id of notification in this method

```
-(void)cancelNotificationForId:(NSString*)id {

    NSArray *notifs = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications];
    for (UILocalNotification *notification in notifs) {
        if ([[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"alarm_id"] isEqualToString:id]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
        }
    }

}
```

Try this method

Comment: Nope i did not use it.I believe it is helpful in the case where you want to remove the UILocalNotification when the event is fired.Probably IM not too sure. 
When i click a button that Clears the DB, Notifications still tend to pop even the event is no longer available in DB. @manujmv

Comment: @MohammedNaveedShaikh: as local notifications are not bound to your db but to iPhone OS, only removing them from your DB will not work. You must cancel them.

Comment: @MohammedNaveedShaikh: No. u r mistaken the purpose of cancelLocalNotification. CancelLocalNotification is used to stop scheduling

Comment: @manujmv : Okay !! thank You for that.Hey this is the hierarchy i have 3fields and i have a save button that triggers notification to fire based on the time set.But when i clear the DB the notification still fires even thou there is nothing in the DB.I Hope you get it.If not share your e-mail add i will mail you the code.

Answer (score 0):

For more reference regarding the terms mentioned in answers by user2339310 and manujmv, please refer [Apple Documentation for Canceling Local Notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelLocalNotification%3a). This will clear the concept of UILocalNotification and there cancellation.