# Remove the UILocalNotification after firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.alertBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"meeting schedule from %@ ",[namelist objectAtIndex:i]];
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.soundName = @"meetting.mp3";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"timerInvoked" object:self];
```

I am using the above code to create local notifications. But previous notifications are not cleared. It again fires when new notifications are fired.

I use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];`

The notification is not fired in the back ground. How do I remove the notification after it has fired?

Comment: Where you are setting `firedate` of local notification? Did you really getting notification?

Comment: I am using Local notification to send the  information to notification from service

Comment: I guess you dont have clear idea about local notification. I'am not sure you want UILocalNotification or NSNotification. Could you clarify your requirements?

Comment: I am new bee to ios.I am using Local notification for the below scenario.                                                               I am creating chat application..when messages arrived from service I send the information to Notification.It displayed in the notification but when new data is occurred it sends the new messages with  old message

Answer (score 0):

`cancelAllLocalNotifications` removes pending notifications. I don't think you can remove notifications from notification center once they have been fired. The user sets (via Settings app) the number of notifications they want to keep and they are automatically removed once the number exceeds that limit.

Comment: I am new bee to ios.I am using Local notification for the below scenario.                                                               I am creating chat application..when messages arrived from service I send the information to Notification.It displayed in the notification but when new data is occurred it sends the new messages with  old message

Comment: Is it just that you don't remove the notification (or open the app from the notification). So when another message is received you now have 2 visible notifications? That is how it should be...

Comment: You may want to look at using `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to show how many unread messages there are.

Comment: I want to clear the previous notification..when i click the notification which is arrived app in back ground app crashes..and notification is not cleared

Comment: You can't remove the notification. Just fix the crash so the app works properly...

Comment: can u suggest the reason for crash

Comment: Not without you showing the code, exception message and stack trace - that is a different question...

Answer (score 0):

When the application receives a local notification, the following method will get called. Put it in the app delegate:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSInteger badgeNumber = [app applicationIconBadgeNumber];// Take the current badge number
    badgeNumber--;    // decrement by one 
    [app setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeNumber];  // set ne badge number
    [app cancelLocalNotification:notification];    // cancel the received notification. It will clear the notification from banner alos
}
```

Comment: This code working as same as before.It display with old messages

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to remove specific notifications after they've fired, you'll need to store them.

After:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

You would also save it in NSUserDefaults, using NSKeyedArchiver to convert it to NSData.

```
NSData *notificationData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:localNotification];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:notificationData forKey:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%d", someKeyOfYourChoice]];
```

To get it back as UILocalNotification you use NSKeyedUnarchiver. Then you're able to delete it using the cancelLocalNotification method.

Further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32389835/2829102) (Swift version + link to original Obj-C solution)