# ios second time set to localnofication fireDate its not working properly

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Please Give me Solution i am Wating 
i have make one Alarm app ,alarm time i have set on local notification fireDate its working properly , and then i try to second time (Snooze time after 1 mint ) i can't able to set local notification , when i try to set second time local notification it's not fire on time otherwise its fire immediately WHERE I DO MISTAKE 
HERE IS MY CODE

```
int getTrackValue=[[defaults valueForKey:@"alarmTrack"] intValue];
     NSString *soundName =[appDelegte.globalArrayTrack objectAtIndex:getTrackValue];
    // set up the notifier
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

    localNotification.fireDate = notiAlarmTime;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    localNotification.alertBody=@"Please Off Alarm";
    localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Show", nil);
    localNotification.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.m4a",soundName];//@"Gentle Rise.m4a";
    localNotification.hasAction = YES;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

second time i am just change the time and call same function 
Please HELP ME 
Please share your valuable knowledge

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a `UILocalNotification` as soon as its scheduled , if you want to change the fireDate you should `cancel the notification reschedule it`.

**Cancel Notificatifcation**

```
 int getTrackValue=[[defaults valueForKey:@"alarmTrack"] intValue];
 NSString *soundName =[appDelegte.globalArrayTrack objectAtIndex:getTrackValue];
// set up the notifier

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

localNotification.fireDate = notiAlarmTime;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
localNotification.alertBody=@"Please Off Alarm";
localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Show", nil);
localNotification.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.m4a",soundName];//@"Gentle Rise.m4a";
localNotification.hasAction = YES;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Relevant question:[Delete a particular local notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340664/delete-a-particular-local-notification)

Comment: i use this line before set notification but not working 
i have set [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

Comment: Please help me , i don't undastand what shoud i do .

Comment: look at my edited answer , it should work , be sure check your fire date is right.

Comment: yes my date is right and i used this code not working

Comment: you keep saying not working , what happened? nothing is  fired ? try to describe your situation . because there is nothing wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

ONE `UILocalNotification` only fires once.

to have MULTIPLE you need multiple `UILocalNotification` objects