# Need assistance how to check region based UILocalNotification is fired or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, appdelegate, clregion

I am trying to figure out how to check if region based `UILocalNotification` is fired or not. I searched and found this [Remove fired Location-Based notification when user exits region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646853/remove-fired-location-based-notification-when-user-exits-region) but its not helpful for me.

I have configured an region based `UILocalNotification` which will fire when user will enter that particular region and `UILocalNotification` will deliver when app is closed.

Now when user open the app how I can check that region based `UILocalNotification` fired or not.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet:

```
    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification

    {

        NSString *regionIdentifier = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"regionIdentifier”];

        [self removeExistingNotificationWithIdentifier: regionIdentifier];

     }



    -(void)removeExistingNotificationWithIdentifier:(NSString*)regionIdentifier
    {
        NSArray *scheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications];
        for (UILocalNotification *notification in scheduledNotifications)
        {
            NSDictionary *userInfoDict = notification.userInfo;
            if ([[userInfoDict objectForKey:@"regionIdentifier"] isEqualToString:regionIdentifier])
            {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelLocalNotification:notification];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some context around your answer.

Comment: The  above methods are used to receive local notifications and then delete them from the scheduled notifications. Please ask clearly what you want to know.

Answer (score -1):

Use `gpx` file to check for region based notifications.

Example: Create a file `Location.gpx` containing the lat,long of the locations you want the notifications to be fired. The below code contains the lat,long of two locations.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode">
    <wpt lat="28.53191" lon="77.38311">
        <name>Google</name>
    </wpt>
    <wpt lat="28.50848" lon="77.40825">
        <name>Apple</name>
    </wpt>
</gpx>
```

While debugging, select the `Location.gpx` file as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: I didnt ask that, I asked is my notification is fired or not.

Comment: If your notification is fired, UIApplicationDelegate's [application:didReceiveLocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:) method will be called and you can extract the information from userInfo dictionary of notification.

Comment: But my app is closed when the notification is delivered.

Comment: whenever you tap on the notification, iOS will run the app in background and [application:didReceiveLocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:) will be called where you will get the reference of the tapped notification.

Comment: Can you write a bit detail snippet that will fetch the fired region based localnotification objects so those objects can be deleted. And remember app is in terminated state when notification is delivered. And I dont want to tap on notification, I will open the app by tapping on its icon.

Comment: without tapping on notification? if you just open the app you won't get any callback of the notification. The app will just be opened normally.

Comment: To get a callback for the notification you need to tap on it.

Comment: you are an amateur you have no knowledge for this.

Comment: if you have so much knowledge then why don't you try it yourself instead of asking these stupid questions.