# DatePicker Local Notification(Xcode,swift2)

Tags: xcode, swift, datepicker, notifications

I am using localNotifications for my app.I have a datepicker from which a users picks date and time for the notifications and I also have 3 segmented controls(daily,weekly,monthly).I have done the coding for localnotification and its working.But the segmented control is not working and one more problem if a person chooses two times like one for(1 pm) and second for (2pm) and then the notifications are displaying in both time which i dont want.Below is the code

In appdelegate.swift

```
    let types:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound

    let myAlarmSetting:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: categories as Set<NSObject>)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(myAlarmSetting)
```

In notifications.swift
 @IBAction func NotificationButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    var notifications:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notifications.fireDate = datePicker.date
    notifications.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    notifications.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
    notifications.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    switch(frequencysegmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex){
    case 0:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
        break;
    case 1:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear
        break;
    case 2:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear
        break;
    default:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit(0)
        break;
    }
    notifications.alertBody = "quote of the day"
    notifications.category = "First_category"

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notifications)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can help you with your two times Local notification problem.

**Solution:**

The problem is that when you add any local notification - First of all you need to check that if any local notification is scheduled or not?

> So, how we can check?

Well, you need to store some data for that in `notifications.userInfo`.
E.g.

```
var userInfo = [String:String]()
let example = "SomeNotification"
userInfo["example"] = example
notification.userInfo = userInfo
```

Reference: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/21/2/scheduling-notifications-uilocalnotification

So, once you update the time for the same notification, you need to cancel the existing notification and set the new notification with new time.

```
var app:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
for oneEvent in app.scheduledLocalNotifications {
    var notification = oneEvent as UILocalNotification
    let userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo! as [String:AnyObject]
    let uid = userInfoCurrent["uid"]! as String
    if uid == uidtodelete {
        //Cancelling local notification
        app.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
        break;
    }
}
```

Reference: [Delete a particular local notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340664/delete-a-particular-local-notification)

Comment: where should i include the first userinfo in which fiile @sohilrmemon

Comment: @Motivationgym5 In file, you are setting your first ever local notification

Comment: in your code  if uid == uidtodelete is showing in error

Comment: @Motivationgym5 that's just an example! You have to remove the same key which you have store at the time of setting the notification. So, make sure that the name for the key remains same

Comment: ah okay and can u please see my code in notification.repeatinterval = nscalendarunit.calendarunit day can you please correct it ?

Comment: @Motivationgym5 see this: I have modified your code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b2e7c640a7c79bc1e3de

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85467/discussion-between-motivation-gym5-and-sohil-r-memon).