# Remove Push Notification Server ApI

Tags: android, python, ios, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to remove particular push notification message from an ios device or apns api using message Id

Currently I am sending the notification using

```
 data = json.dumps({"to" : gcm_token,
                            "content_available":False,
                            "priority": "high",
                            "notification": { "sound":"default",
                                              "badge":"1",
                                              "click-action":activityName,
                                              "body":subject}
                            })

 request_header={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'key=%s'%(Auth_Key)}

 request = urllib2.Request('https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send', data, headers=request_header)
 response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Badge, found in your code, is a number that indicates number of incoming messages displayed in the corner of client app home icon. You can remove the notifications by setting `badge` to 0 as discussed in [Push Notifications Tutorial: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial).

But if you want to remove a specific notification, solutions were already given in SO post - [Delete a particular local notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340664/delete-a-particular-local-notification). I hope it helps. :)

Comment: But if the cases like gmail where two notification sent to mobile and same user reads it from web I want to update and remove the particular notification how can i do that