# How to cancel a local notification trigger in Swift

Tags: swift, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest

I have a trigger to show a notification to the user:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Title"
content.body = "Body"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 20, repeats: false)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "TestIdentifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

Is there a way for me to cancel that trigger once it has been set?

How do I cancel the notification before the `timeInterval` runs out and call the notification?

Comment: What did you mean by asking this? The system counts the active notifications only.

Comment: @Mannopson I ask, let's say I opened a trigger to show a local notification in 15 min, but after 10 minutes I want to cancel that trigger to not show the notification how do I do that?

Comment: Use the `removePendingNotificationsWithIdentifier`. You can cancel the notifications by given identifier.

Comment: @Mannopson can u write that as an answer ? i'll give u the correct answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a particular local notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340664/delete-a-particular-local-notification)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can cancel or remove notifications by calling:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
```

Remove pending notifications with given identifier

```
center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [“givenIdentifier”])
```

And remove delivered notifications with given identifier

```
center.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [“givenIdentifier”])
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on top of Mannopson's answer:

This removes all pending Notifications (**Swift 5**)

```
func cancelNotifications() -> Void {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
}
```