# Obj-C, how do I delete a local push notification set previously?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

I know it's possible to delete a local push notification ([How to delete a local notification in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372387/how-to-delete-a-local-notification-in-iphone))

But what if my users set a notification a week ago?

How can I iterate through these notifications, find the one I want to delete and delete it?

I'm guessing that they must be app specific, so I could delete all the notifications and then have a routine which submits new ones?

Are there any good examples or tutorials online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of all scheduled local notifications with:

```
NSArray* notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

You can then iterate through that array and create a new array.
Since iOS 4.2 you can then schedule the new notification array easily with:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications = notifications;
```

Earlier you had to call `scheduleLocalNotification:` for each new notification.

Comment: Can I delete all the notifications for my app? maybe that's the best option for compatibility with older phones. But can I delete all from my app ?

Comment: @Jules deletes all scheduled notifications: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications = [NSArray array];`

Answer (score 4):

To delete all of your local notifications, you can do the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Have fun!