# Xcode how to clear notification center

Tags: xcode, nsnotificationcenter

On load of the the app will clear out all notifications in the notification center.  How do I do that?

edit:  I do not want to delete the actual notification, I want to clear the it from notification center (the swipe down menu).  The notification is reoccurring so do not want to clear it.

This is the case; notification goes off, the phone is locked.  The user unlocks the phone and does other things on the phone.  Then later goes into my app.  After exiting the app the notification center still shows the notification.  Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Answered here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372387/how-to-delete-a-local-notification-in-iphone

Comment: That is not what I want to do.  I edit my post with this detail.  The app has a reoccurring notification, for example the notification goes off every Monday.  That notification needs to stay.  Need to clear the notification center (the swipe down menu).