# Dismiss all notifications in iOS 8 and Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uilocalnotification, localnotification

Is there a way to programmatically dismiss all local notifications? My app has local notifications everyday, but if a user doesn't dismiss them, I don't want them to pile up for the user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS find list of Local Notification the app has already set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531332/ios-find-list-of-local-notification-the-app-has-already-set)

Comment: UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications(). You could find this al over the internet but whatever.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a local notification in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372387/how-to-delete-a-local-notification-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()`